# Asynchronous execution in separate domains

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, appdomain

How to execute code asynchronously in separate domains ?

For example, I have a method :

```
public void DoSomething()
    {
        // do something
    }
```

And I want to execute it in 10 different domains, like this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("NewDomain - " + i);
            domain.ExecuteAsync(DoSomething);
        }
```

Comment: Why would you do so? You could do it on different threads.

Comment: I want to simulate requests to WCF service from different users via AppDomain's.

Comment: You can simply spawn more threads and do it

Comment: I did via threads. when I increased number of working threads, CPU usage equal to 50%, but time for executing increasing.

Comment: but if I execute several instances of my app, CPU full loaded (100%)

Comment: so I think that usage of AppDomain can help me do it in context of ONE processs

Comment: @ZuTa: It's still not clear why you think that AppDomains would help. Without knowing what the asynchronous task is or the bottleneck, it's hard to help further. For example, it may well just be a connection pool issue, where the HTTP stack is limiting the number of concurrent connections to a host.

Comment: If you have two cpu core machine, run two instances of application which internally spawns several threads. This should be sufficient. Further, check what is consuming the CPU, wcf service or your test application.

Comment: Further, if you are using SQLExpress in your WCF service, it will never use the second core of your CPU as Express version always uses only one cpu in a multi core cpu environment.

Comment: @JonSkeet: yeah. you're right. maybe my questions isn't quite clear. My task : create WCF-client which must call WCF-service's methods from different "users". So, my first implementation was via threads. but its load a CPU only to 50%. but I want to load it for maximum(increasing number of working threads\).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my task using this approach :

```
for (int i = 0; i < options.NumberOfThreads; i++)
            {
                tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        using (Isolated<TesterInvoker> isolated = new Isolated<TesterInvoker>())
                        {
                            isolated.Value.Invoke();
                        }
                    });                 
            }

private class TesterInvoker : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public void Invoke()
        {
            // do something
        }
    }

    private class Isolated<T> : IDisposable 
        where T : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        private AppDomain _domain;
        private T _value;

        public Isolated()
        {
            Type type = typeof(T);

            _domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Isolated:" + GetHashCode(),
               null, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation);

            _value = (T)_domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(type.Assembly.FullName, type.FullName);
        }

        public T Value
        {
            get
            {
                return _value;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_domain != null)
            {
                AppDomain.Unload(_domain);

                _domain = null;
            }
        }
    }
```